# Wrong extension-method gets called

Tags: c#, generics

I created the following extension methods in a .Net 5 webapi project :

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> Filter<TSource>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> query, IEnumerable<string> filter) where TSource : IModel
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser> Filter(this IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser> query, IEnumerable<string> filter)
    {
        return query
            .Where(x => filter.Any(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email) && x.Email.Contains(str, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

The generic one is just a 'placeholder'. I use these methods in some service classes in a service-repository pattern.

The base service class :

```
public class DataServiceBase<T> : IDataService<T> where T : class, IModel, new()
{
    public IValidationDictionary ValidationDictionary { get; }
    protected readonly IRepository<T> Repo;

    public DataServiceBase(IRepository<T> repo, IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
    {
        Repo = repo;
        ValidationDictionary = validationDictionary;
    }

    public virtual IOrderedQueryable<T> Read(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        return Repo.Read().OrderBy(x => x.Id);
    }

    public virtual IOrderedQueryable<T> Read(ApplicationContext applicationContext, ReadListSettings readListSettings)
    {
        var query = Read(applicationContext);
        if (readListSettings.Filter != null)
        {
            // HERE THE EXTENSIONS METHOD IS USED
            query = query.Filter(readListSettings.Filter.Process());
            // HERE THE EXTENSIONS METHOD IS USED
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

And a specific one :

```
public partial class ApplicationUserService : DataServiceBase<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserService(
        IRepository<ApplicationUser> repo,
        IValidationDictionary validationDictionary
    ) : base(repo, validationDictionary)    {}

    public override IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser> Read(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        return Repo
            .Read()
            .Include(x => x.User2UserGroups)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.UserGroup)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Tenant)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Email);
    }
}
```

I would expect that when calling ApplicationUserService.Read(applicationcontext, readlistsettings) the specific version of the extensionmethod is called. I checked the type and the generic method gets the correct class as its TSource.

I tried adding the following to my AppUserService, but still the TSource-version gets called.

```
public override IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser> Read(ApplicationContext applicationContext, ReadListSettings readListSettings)
{
    return base.Read(applicationContext, readListSettings);
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you need a "placeholder" method? Unlike an abstract method, a static method is always resolved at compile time.

Comment: If there is not that 'placeholder'. The project does not build. 'IOrderedQueryable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Filter' and the best extension method overload 'QueryableExtensions.Filter(IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser>, IEnumerable<string>)' requires a receiver of type 'IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser>'

Comment: @BrilBroeder: if `Repo` wraps EF context, you should note, that `Filter` will throw exception, since condition in `Where` can't be translated into SQL.

Comment: This is not how polymorphism works. To make it work, create an abstract `Filter` method in your `DataServiceBase` class and just override it in concrete services.

Comment: @Dennis if I just copy the code of the Read(.... readlistsettings) method to the specific service, it just works fine.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I like DNRY. Addint that method to the service would be copying that code over and over again.

Comment: sorry guys. was on the wrong track about copying code. The sample code by Dennis cleared that up. Both thx for the input.

Comment: @BrilBroeder If it does not build without that placeholder, then there's obviously something wrong with the types and the method you actually want cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods are not about polymorphism.
Given these models and settings:

```
    public interface IModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUser : IModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReadListSettings
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Filter { get; set; }
    }
```

your custom filtering could be implemented like this:

```
    public abstract class DataServiceBase<T>
        where T : IModel
    {
        public IOrderedQueryable<T> Read()
        {
            // gets queryable from repository somehow
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable().OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        }

        public IOrderedQueryable<T> Read(ReadListSettings readListSettings)
        {
            var query = Read();
            if (readListSettings.Filter != null)
            {
                // use custom filtering in descendatns here
                query = Filter(query, readListSettings.Filter);
            }

            return query;
        }

        protected virtual IOrderedQueryable<T> Filter(IOrderedQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<string> filter) => query;
    }

    public partial class ApplicationUserService : DataServiceBase<ApplicationUser>
    {
        protected override IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser> Filter(IOrderedQueryable<ApplicationUser> query, IEnumerable<string> filter)
        {
            return query
                .Where(x => filter.Any(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email) && x.Email.Contains(str, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        }
    }
```

(I've simplified your types, and left relevant code only)